# PHP IMAP extract mail attachment in gmail

Tags: php, gmail, imap, attachment

I am trying to extract the attachment of an email, its structure is as follows:

```
stdClass Object ( [type] => 3 [encoding] => 3 [ifsubtype] => 1 [subtype] => PDF [ifdescription] => 1 [description] => 3002024147 [ifid] => 0 [bytes] => 90256 [ifdisposition] => 0 [ifdparameters] => 0 [ifparameters] => 1 [parameters] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attribute] => NAME [value] => 3002024147.pdf ) ) )
```

I have tried in the following way:

foreach($emails as $email_number) {

```
        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);

        /* get mail message */
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        /* get mail structure */
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);

        $attachments = array();

        /* if any attachments found... */
        if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) 
            {
                $attachments[$i] = array(
                    'is_attachment' => false,
                    'filename' => '',
                    'name' => '',
                    'attachment' => ''
                );

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) 
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) 
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') 
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) 
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) 
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') 
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) 
                {
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1);

                    /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) 
                    { 
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                    /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */
                    elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) 
                    { 
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /* iterate through each attachment and save it */
        foreach($attachments as $attachment)
        {
            if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
            {
                $filename = $attachment['name'];
                if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];

                if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . ".dat";

                $fp = fopen($email_number . "-" . $filename, "w+");
                fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
                fclose($fp);
            }

        }
```

}

I manage to extract the email attachment that I send from Apple Mail and others, but the ones I receive with the previous structure do not.

What I can do?